# Magento 2.3: Error on admin product save after changing attribute set

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute, attribute-set

I am getting this error after I change the attribute set and save the product:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackendTable() on boolean in /chroot/home/aa8492ec/018d4ad51c.nxcli.net/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php:350 Stack trace: #0 /chroot/home/aa8492ec/018d4ad51c.nxcli.net/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(331): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->deleteSelectedEntityAttributeRows(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array) #1 /chroot/home/aa8492ec/018d4ad51c.nxcli.net/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(304): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->removeNotInSetAttributeValues(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) #2 /chroot/home/aa8492ec/018d4ad51c.nxcli.net/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1942): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->_afterSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) #3 /chroot/home/aa8492ec/018d4ad51c.nxcli.net/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceMod in /chroot/home/aa8492ec/018d4ad51c.nxcli.net/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php on line 350
```

Any help would be appreciated.